# CloudFront: why an Admin is not authorized to perform invalidation action?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to create an invalidation using both the aws cli and the PHP SDK, using an administrator IAM (full rights).

Here's the command line

```
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id=E2NYX13BG????? --paths "/*"
```

But I always get this error message:

```
Error: User: arn:aws:iam::5253618?????:user/algo is not authorized to perform: 
cloudfront:CreateInvalidation on resource: 
arn:aws:cloudfront::5253618?????:distribution/E2NYX13BG?????
```

**EDIT ---**

To clarify my doubt about this. There are two other questions [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710607/accessdenied-user-is-not-authorized-to-perform-cloudfrontcreateinvalidation) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710607/accessdenied-user-is-not-authorized-to-perform-cloudfrontcreateinvalidation), as pasted in comments by @amitd. Both questions are referencing possible non-admin rights, and also possible restricted CloudFront resources.

BY "administrator" I mean that the the IAM account has these rights to the my whole AWS services:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

As can be seen above, resources are not being restricted, so must I still create a different Statement item to add `"Resource": "*"`, to CloudFront? Because it would make not sense at all.

Comment: similar to these two posts: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710607/accessdenied-user-is-not-authorized-to-perform-cloudfrontcreateinvalidation) and  [two](https://serverfault.com/questions/735054/access-denied-when-calling-the-createinvalidation-operation-on-aws-cli)

Comment: @amitd, I actually searched this and found both questions before posting my own, but I just edited it to clarify